# Xamarin Tap Event Not Working for iOS but Working for Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am facing issues with Xamarin, such that the ItemTapped event is not triggering under iOS, nor is the selection of items working. Everything works fine for the Android build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an issue with iOS 13.4 and Xcode 11.4. The error occurs if you update to the latest version.

> After upgrading to xcode 11.4 and iOS 13.4 GestureRecognizers
>   (TapGestureRecognizer) have stopped working on iOS. Android works as
>   expected.

An issue has been raised on GitHub and a fix should be available within the next two weeks.

Source: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10162

Comment: Thanks, from earlier today I was also facing same issue.

Comment: As far as I understand from the issue, this happens only on simulator?

Comment: Nope, it also happens on the device. I tried it via TestFlight... Unfortunately:(

Answer (score 1):

I just made an update to VS 2019 @ 16.5.3 and the ItemTapped event works on iOS 13.4.

When I connected to our Mac, an update to Xamarin.Ios was also necessary - v13.16.0.13.

We had the same problem on our production app and we used iOS 12.4 on the simulator.

From my point of view, the update fixed our problem.

Comment: Why did you have to update the Xamarin.Ios SDK? I thought that comes shipped with the VS update?

Comment: The connection with the Mac demanded it. There was a version mismatch and either I updated the SDK or cancel the connection to our Mac.

Answer (score 0):

The fix for me was install xamarin.ios-13.14.1.39 in MAC and re-build.

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/8f94ca38-039a-4c9f-a51a-a6cb33c76a8c/21e09d8084eb7c15eaa07c970e0eccdc/xamarin.ios-13.14.1.39.pkg

Comment: The fix was released today as part of the VS update

Comment: VS for MAC or VS for Windows? Or both VS? I am working with Windows and MAC.

Comment: For both. See version 16.5.3